# Magento 2.4.3 homepage not loading correctly

Tags: magento2.4.3

I have recently installed Magento 2.4.3(p1) after successful installation, the homepage not working correctly and displaying like this :
[image]

Comment: Whats your mode developer i think the issue linked to static element

Comment: Why pub in url path? Which server are you using (apache/nginx)? Please, check docs and configure the server correctly. Keep in mind, Magento does not support the Windows system.

Comment: Did you deploy the statics ? Check the other pages if they are the same. Also as said above, the pub in url looks strange.

Comment: magento serve whole website from pub folder tahtswhy i've used it in url

Comment: using apache server

Answer (score 0):

issue resolved!!
my URL was incorrect that why its showing me pages like that

go to dB and use this query :

```
SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE PATH LIKE "%url%"
```

and in my case it was:

```
http://localhost/magento24/
```

I set it to:

```
http://localhost:8021/magento24/pub/
```

and its working!!.